# incompatible types possible lossy conversion from double to int

Tags: java

im trying to add a Grand Total to my dialog box but i get an error message and i cant seem to fix it. if i try to put the Grand Total in my for loop it just prints out 5 times in the dialog box. i do need to have the Grand Total print last in the dialog box

```
import javax.swing. JOptionPane;

public class BookTest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        double charge;
        double grandTotal= 0;


        String dataArray[][] = {{"Abraham Lincoln Vampire Hunter","Grahame-Smith","978-0446563079","13.99", "Haper", "NY"},
                    {"Frankenstein","Shelley","978-0486282114","7.99","Pearson", "TX"},
                    {"Dracula","Stoker","978-0486411095","5.99","Double Day", "CA"},
                    {"Curse of the Wolfman"," Hageman","B00381AKHG","10.59","Harper", "NY"},
                    {"The Mummy","Rice","978-0345369949","7.99","Nelson", "GA"}};




        Book bookArray[] = new Book[dataArray.length];

        int quantityArray[] = {12, 3, 7, 23, 5};

        for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++)
        {
            bookArray[i] = new Book(dataArray[i][0], dataArray[i][1], dataArray[i][2], 
                Double.parseDouble(dataArray[i][3]), new Publisher(dataArray[i][4], dataArray[i][5]));
        }

        String msg = " ";



        for (int i = 0; i < bookArray.length; i++)
        {

            charge = bookArray[i].calculateTotal(quantityArray[i]);

            grandTotal = charge + grandTotal;

            msg += String.format(" %s, %s, $%.2f\n", bookArray[i].getTitle(), bookArray[i].getIsbn(), charge); 


        }


        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, "Grand Total $%.2f ", grandTotal); //

    }

}
```

Comment: You mentioned an error message: what is the message, and which line does it indicate?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to pass `grandTotal` as the message type of [`showMessageDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showMessageDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-java.lang.String-int-).

I suspect what you meant is something like the following:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(
    null, msg,
    String.format("Grand Total $%.2f", grandTotal),
    JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE
);
```

Also see [*"How to Make Dialogs"*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html).

Comment: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, String.format("Grand Total $%.2f ", grandTotal)); i dont think its my comma placement??